# How to select proper values to solve Bunch-Davies initial condition?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, astrophysics, vacuum, cosmological-inflation

I am trying to solve the Mukhanov-Sasaki equation for a Starobinsky potential $V(\phi(t))=3/4m^2M_P^2(1-e^{-\sqrt{2/3}\phi(t)})^2$. I could change the equations so that $m^2$ does not appear and chose $c,M_P,G,h=1$, and then I solved the Klein-Gordon equations with Mathematica for $\phi(t),\ a(t)$. Now, after calculating $n_s$ and the primordial power spectrum, I want to solve the before mentioned equation.

However, in order to do that, I have to solve the Bunch-Davies state for initial conditions. I have

\begin{align*}
u_k(\tau)=\lim_{k/(a_*H_*)\rightarrow\infty}\frac{e^{-ik\tau}}{\sqrt{2k}}
\end{align*}

where $k/(a_*H_*)$ is the quotient of a scale and a pivot scale. My doubt is how do I choose $\tau$ and $k$ to be in order to solve my initial conditions? I know that $k>>aH$, but does that mean $\tau$ has to be the same as the one evaluated for the $k$? I know that $\tau(t)-\tau(0)=\int_0^ta(t')dt'$ and $k=\dot{a}$, but how do I choose the values for $k$ and $\tau$?

\begin{align*}
u''_k+[k^2-(aH)^2(2-\epsilon_1+3/2\epsilon_2-1/2\epsilon_1\epsilon_2+1/4\epsilon_2^2+1/2\epsilon_2\epsilon_3)]u_k&=0\\
u&\cong aQ
\end{align*}

Plus, since I am solving the system for a specific $k$, does that mean that the Mukhanov-Sasaki solution is unique for each $k>>aH$? Or is one unique solution for all of these $k$'s?

Comment: Can't anyone give an answer?